# zsh prompt - checking if there are any background jobs

Tags: zsh, background-process, prompt

I'm customizing my zsh prompt and have found the following to check if there are any background jobs:

```
if [[ $(jobs | wc -l) -gt 0 ]]; then # has background job(s)
    number_jobs='J:${cyan}%j${no_color}'
else # no background job(s)
    number_jobs=""
fi
```

The problem I'm facing is that the code appears to be evaluated only when I open a new session rather than after each command making this rather useless. How can I have `number_jobs` re-evaluated after each command?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

zsh has a special prompt sequence, like C ternary operator. The below construction means if there are one or more jobs then print their number or print nothing:

```
 %(1j.%j.)
```

Comment: Does the 1j portion state "if there is one job" or "if there are more than one jobs"? (excuse my ignorance of C, I'm new to all this)

Comment: any number of jobs (1, 2, more)

Comment: Just for the reference for folks like me who would like to find the docs: both `%(...)` and `%j` can be found in `man zshmisc`, in "expansion of prompt sequences" section (the ternary operation is in "conditional substrings in prompts" subsection).